# How to fullscreen image and dismiss with swipe similar to Apple Photos

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

How can I implement the fullscreen image and dismiss image functionality of the Apple Photos? Additionally, how can I get the aspect ratio of an image to fit within a fullscreen view? Are they sending a UIImage to a new view controller?

My current method of fullscreening an image simply sets a UIImageView's frame equal to the superview's frame while turning the alphas of the UINavigationBar and UITabBar to 0. And to dismiss, I added a tap gesture recognizer that reverses the alphas and removes the UIImageView from the superview.

Here's my fullscreen and dismiss code

```
func fullscreen(forImage image: UIImage) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = self.view.frame
    imageView.backgroundColor = .black
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 0

    let dismissTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could easily be achieved using Apple's [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) framework as it works great for many extensions and collections of images.

Edit: Most of the functionality you want is built into the `QLPreviewController`

```
let previewController = QLPreviewController()
previewController.dataSource = self
self.present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The data source is whatever class conforms to the `QLPreviewControllerDataSource` protocol

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/237/) is a video guide from apple on how to achieve this easily

Edit: This part goes in the `previewItemAt` function

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "imageName", withExtension: "jpg")
     else {
        fatalError("Could not load imageName.jpg")
     }

return url as QLPreviewItem
```

Comment: QuickLook requires URLs for its QLPreviewItems. I have some images loaded into my project from Assets.xcassets. Do you know how I can turn those into URLs or still use those images for QuickLook?

Comment: Images stored in the Assets.xcassets folder do not have URL paths as they get converted to a binary like file but if you put the images inside another folder that isn't an assets folder then you can look at my edit to see how its done. @Explorer